# Add .gz files to tar.gz file but decode gz before adding. Output files getting clipped (corrupted)

Tags: go

Below I have a snippet of my code which collects some gzip compressed PDF files.

I want to add the PDF's to a `tar.gz` file, but before adding them they need to be uncompressed (gzip). Don't want to end up with a `tar.gz` filled with `pdf.gz` files

Need to decompress it without reading the entire file into memory. The PDF files in the `tar.gz` are clipped and corrupted. When I compare the `tar.gz` files with the original PDF files the look equal except the `tar.gz` files are clipped. The last part of each file is missing

```
// Create new gz writer with compression level 1
gzw, _ := gzip.NewWriterLevel(w, 1)
defer gzw.Close()

// Create new tar writer
tw := tar.NewWriter(gzw)
defer tw.Close()

file_path := "path-to-file.pdf.gz"
file_name := "filename-shown-in-tar.pdf"

// Open file to add to tar
fp, err := os.Open(file_path)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
defer fp.Close()

file_name := file[1]+file_ext

info, err   := fp.Stat()
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, file_name)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
header.Name = file_name

tw.WriteHeader(header)

// This part will write the *.pdf.gz files directly to the tar.gz file
// This part works and it's possible to both open the tar.gz file and
// afterwards open the individuel pdf.gz files
//io.Copy(tw, fp)

// This part decode the gz before adding, but it clips the pdf files in
// the tar.gz file
gzr, err := gzip.NewReader(fp)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
defer gzr.Close()
io.Copy(tw, gzr)
```

## update

Got a suggestion from a comment, but now the PDF files inside the tar can't be opened. The tar.gz file is created and can be opened, but the PDF files inside are corrupted

Have tried to compare output files from the `tar.gz` with the original PDF. It looks like the corrupted file is missing the last bit of the file.

In one example the original file has 498 lines and the corrupted has only 425. But it looks like the 425 lines are equal to the original. Somehow the last bit is just clipped

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for your contribution, but it still doesn't work. Or it works but the PDF files inside the tar can't be opened.. Have added your suggestion

Comment: @CeriseLimón Have tried to compare files from your suggestion with the original PDF. It looks like the corrupted file is missing the last bit of the file. The original file has 498 lines and the corrupted has only 425. But it looks like the 425 lines are equal to the original. Somehow the last bit is just clipped

Comment: (1) Check errors.  (2) Ensure that the deferred Close calls execute before trying to read the file.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Have added error handlers.. (see updated question) What do you mean by (2) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're setting the file info header based on the original file, which is compressed. In particular, it is the size that is causing problems - if you attempt to write in excess of the size indicated by the `Size` value in the header, `archive/tar.Writer.Write()` will return `ErrWriteTooLong` - see https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d5efd0dd63a8beb5cc57ae7d25f9c60d5dea5c65/src/archive/tar/writer.go#L428-L429

Something like the following should work, whereby the file is uncompressed and read so an accurate size can be established:

```
// Open file to add to tar
fp, err := os.Open(file_path)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
defer fp.Close()

gzr, _ := gzip.NewReader(fp)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer gzr.Close()

data, err := io.ReadAll(gzr)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}

// Create tar header for file
header := &tar.Header{
    Name: file_name,
    Mode: 0600,
    Size: int64(len(data)),
}

// Write header to the tar
if err = tw.WriteHeader(header); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}

// Write the file content to the tar
if _, err = tw.Write(data); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error: %v", err)
}
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense.. But is it not possible to do it without reading the entire file first? That was what I tried to avoid

Comment: is it not possible to read the length of the buffer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66725860/determine-length-of-golang-gzip-file-without-reading-it/66725937#66725937 for the answer to that

Comment: ok.. thanks.. seems like only way is to read the entire file as you suggested